# how to join two consecutive files from a folder (1 with 2, 3 with 4, ...) in bash

Tags: bash

I have a folder with pictures (jpg's). I want to join two consecutive files (1 and 2, 3 and 4, 5 and 6, ....) .

for just two files I use:

```
convert -append First.jpg Second.jpg -quality 50 togetherFirstSecond.jpg
```

I would like to use bash but I don't know how to make a list of files and use it like this:

pseudocode:

```
create a list LIST of files contained in a folder FOLDER
for i in lenght(LIST)/2:
   convert -append LIST(2*i+1) LIST(2*i+2)  -quality 50 togetherLIST(2*i+1)LIST(2*i+2).jpg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting your files on the script's argument vector, and then `shift`ing them off incrementally (removing them from that list), will let you loop through pairs:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -- *.jpg            # set argument list from files matching *.jpg
while (( $# >= 2 )); do # as long as there are two files left...
  first=$1; shift       # ...take the first two off, putting their names in variables 
  second=$1; shift      #    "first" and "second"...
  convert -append "$first" "$second" -quality 50 "together${first%.jpg}${second$.jpg}.jpg"
done
```

`${var%suffix}` removes the suffix from your variable, so `${first%.jpg}` expands to `First` instead of `First.jpg`, preventing your file from having extra extensions embedded within it.

Comment: `--` is an end-of-options sigil; it ensures that following arguments are treated as literal names and not any other kind of option to `set` (like flags to enable or disable, which could happen if you had a name that started with a dash).

Comment: `shift` removes `$1` from the argument list, and makes the old `$2` the new `$1`, the old `$3` the new `$2`, etc; it's how we move through the argument list as we loop.